# MySQL ERROR 1054:UNKNOWN COLUMN 'amount' in field list

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1054

I want to create a trigger so that:

1. if the AMOUNT field < 100 the AMOUNT field automatically inserts 100.
2. If AMOUNT > 100 the entered value should be inserted in the AMOUNT field.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE DB_triggers.acc(
    C_ID INT(3) UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    customer_name CHAR(30),amount FLOAT(10,2) UNSIGNED, 
    date_created DATE,PRIMARY KEY(C_ID,customer_name)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
    CREATE TRIGGER trig_acc
    BEFORE INSERT ON acc

    FOR EACH ROW 

    BEGIN
    IF amount <100 THEN

    INSERT INTO acc VALUES(new.c_id,new.customer_name,100,new.now());
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO acc VALUES(new.c_id,new.customer_name,new.amount,new.now());

    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

BUT, when I insert a value :

```
INSERT INTO 
    acc(c_id,customer_name,amount,date_created) 
VALUES
    (DEFAULT,'ABC',1000,NOW());
```

gives error 1054

Comment: what will happen when amount will be exactly 100?

Answer (score 0):

Change **IF amount <100 THEN** to **IF new.amount <100 THEN** then it will work.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
 CREATE TRIGGER trig_acc
 BEFORE INSERT ON acc
 FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
IF new.amount <100 THEN

INSERT INTO acc VALUES(new.c_id,new.customer_name,100,new.now());
ELSE
     INSERT INTO acc VALUES(new.c_id,new.customer_name,new.amount,new.now());

END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: NOW... I'm getting.... ERROR 1442 : Can't update table 'acc' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: @user1948493 Sorry, I forgot to tell you that you can't insert a row on same table. You can insert a record on another table. I want to know what exacly you want to do by inserting a new record on same table.